# Task Scheduler Application Exit Trigger

Tags: windows, security, scheduled-tasks, kiosk

I'm writing (win7) kiosk software and I want to schedule a "shutdown" bat to run whenever my application exits (Crashed, "Hacked" or Normal Exit) under a specific user account with the task scheduler.

How can I create the *application closed* trigger though?

If it's not possible, my fallback plan is to have some kind of monitor begin in the Application start event but I'm thinking that if my hypothetical hacker could close the main application whats to stop them closing the Monitor process?

**EDIT:** Currently the app is loaded under an *excessively* limited profile with the "runas" directive impersonating an admin user. If the task schedular could be triggered I can also run this batch file from the administrative account on app closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could have your kiosk application create and own a global mutex, and have the monitor application wait on the mutex. The monitor application can be a service so you don't have to worry about starting it from your process. When your application terminates, the monitor will get ownership of the mutex, and as a bonus, if your process terminated unexpectedly (ie does not ever release the mutex properly), then monitor application will have a [AbandonedMutexException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.abandonedmutexexception.aspx) thrown to it. So you'll know if it was a normal shutdown, or a crash/kill. You can run the monitor app under an account with the necessary privileges to do whatever shutdown work is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea.

When your application start you create a schedule of shutdown after 1 minute. And In your application you can set a timmer to delay the schedule periodically. Once your application down and no one delay the schedule so the machine shutdown. Also you should delete the schedule on a normal exit

Comment: good suggestion, but unless theres a "delay" shutdown method in Pinvoke (or I've missed something) the shutdown command would have to be cancelled and restarted. The main application could be completely responsible for itself which makes implementation easy.
Though I'm not sure about the restarting of the command,

Comment: [edit timeout] - putting the functionality within a single (exposed) process does worry me though. Also the lack of visibility of the current shutdown opperation from C# could lead to the application accidentally shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of this is you can't, once an application process terminates, you can't continue to execute code in the same process. Your application monitoring app is the way to go. I'd set it to alert you in some fashion if there was some problem. If you set the polling interval to short enough, it wouldn't seem practical (though possible), to end both apps before sending some kind of an alert.